# Crash in iOS App on Apple Silicon M1 *** Assertion failure in -[_UIRegularOverlayScrollerImp setKnobProportion:], _UIScrollerImp.m:347

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, apple-m1

I am getting an unfamiliar crash log when accessing one of the viewControllers of my iOS app *that has been built as a native app* on an **Apple Silicon M1 Mac**.
It works perfectly well on the simulator and on an iOS device.

Does anybody know what's going on here?

```
2020-12-16 23:02:39.680945+0100 MyApp[45300:9651291] [AXRuntimeCommon] Unknown client: MyApp
2020-12-16 23:02:40.336674+0100 MyApp[45300:9651291] *** Assertion failure in -[_UIRegularOverlayScrollerImp setKnobProportion:], _UIScrollerImp.m:347
2020-12-16 23:03:10.902600+0100 MyApp[45300:9651291] [General] Invalid parameter not satisfying: !isnan(newKnobProportion)
2020-12-16 23:03:10.907684+0100 MyApp[45300:9651291] [General] (
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001912a1320 __exceptionPreprocess + 240
  1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000190fcfc04 objc_exception_throw + 60
  2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001912cc294 -[NSException description] + 0
  3   Foundation                          0x0000000192084bb4 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 132
  4   UIKitCore                           0x00000001b39d4224 -[_UIScrollerImp setKnobProportion:] + 256
  5   UIKitCore                           0x00000001b39d39c4 __54-[UIScrollView _updateScrollerImpsForcingReplacement:]_block_invoke + 272
  6   UIKitCore                           0x00000001b39d0eec -[UIScrollView _updateScrollerImpsForcingReplacement:] + 2844
  7   UIKitCore                           0x00000001b3a32370 -[UIScrollView _willMoveToWindow:] + 200
  8   UIKitCore                           0x00000001b3953268 _makeSubTreePerformSelector + 456
  9   UIKitCore                           0x00000001b3952384 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 452
  10  UIKitCore                           0x00000001b39f2eac -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 608
  11  UIKitCore                           0x00000001b39f0614 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 2736
  12  UIKitCore                           0x00000001b39ef430 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 880
  13  UIKitCore                           0x00000001b3a17300 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 168
  14  UIKitCore                           0x00000001b39fbee0 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 228
  15  UIKit                               0x00000001e0605acc -[UILayoutContainerViewAccessibility layoutSubviews] + 52
  16  UIKitCore                           0x00000001b39a4130 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2552
  17  QuartzCore                          0x00000001974b41a0 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 372
  18  QuartzCore                          0x00000001974b3ad0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 524
  19  QuartzCore                          0x00000001975d7db0 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEdPd + 420
  20  QuartzCore                          0x0000000197492c6c _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 732
  21  UIKitCore                           0x00000001b3905724 _afterCACommitHandler + 144
  22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000191222df8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36
  23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000191222c44 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 576
  24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000191221784 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 684
  25  HIToolbox                           0x0000000198d2af0c RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
  26  HIToolbox                           0x0000000198d2abcc ReceiveNextEventCommon + 320
  27  HIToolbox                           0x0000000198d2aa6c _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 76
  28  AppKit                              0x00000001939f6db0 _DPSNextEvent + 868
  29  AppKit                              0x00000001939f5730 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1312
  30  AppKit                              0x00000001939e758c -[NSApplication run] + 600
  31  AppKit                              0x00000001939b8d74 NSApplicationMain + 1064
  32  AppKit                              0x0000000193caa6a8 +[NSWindow _savedFrameFromString:] + 0
  33  UIKitMacHelper                      0x00000001a3dce388 UINSApplicationMain + 1276
  34  UIKitCore                           0x00000001b38f2a8c UIApplicationMain + 164
  35  MyApp                            0x000000010009c468 main + 128
  36  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000191144f54 start + 4
)
(lldb)
```

Comment: it only happens when running my iOS app on my Mac directly (which is only possible on an M1).

Comment: Edited the question to highlight the platform-specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally solved this one:

The crash was caused by calling `sizeToFit` on a UIView with an invalid frame (contained `Inf`).
Interestingly this only happened when building for Apple Silicon - "My Mac (Designed for iPad)"- target.

This is how I solved it quickly:

```
    if (!CGRectIsEmpty(_infoLabel.frame)) { // this sufficed for me to weed out 'bad' rects
        [_infoLabel sizeToFit];
    }
```